# Render different pages on same route but for different subdomains in a single nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, conditional-rendering, app-router

I have a nextjs 14 frontend app, a python fast api backend. I have app router implemented in the app. I want to create a different website on store.myapp.in which is different from dashboard.myapp.in but they are in same application. Tell me how to implment these logic.

I has layout.js and page.js in src/app and i created @dashboard and @store but I am unable to render them based on subdomain condition

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.